# How to make a new line in Google Data Studio in the exception?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I am writing a connector for Google Data Studio. I want to make a new line in the exception, but it does not work. Here is the code (look getConfig):

```
function getData(request) {
  return {};
}

function isAdminUser() {
  return true;
}

function getConfig(params) {
  throw("1st line\n2nd line<br>3rd line");

  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  var config = cc.getConfig();

  return config.build();
}

function getAuthType() {
    return false;
}


function getSchema(request) {
  return {
    'schema' : 
            [
              {
                  name: "Field_1",
                  dataType: 'STRING',
                  semantics: {
                      conceptType: 'DIMENSION'
                  }
              }
              ]
    }
}
```

And that's what happens (all in one line):
[image]

How do I make a new line in the exception?

Comment: @TheMaster, no, it does not work.

Comment: You may need to double escape `\\n`.

Comment: @c0de, no, it too does not work :-( .

Comment: "throw" statement is not Google DS specific. It is pure JavaScript and can accept a string (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw), not rich text or html.

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин, thanks for the answer. And how to make a new line? I'm newbie, I apologize if the question is stupid.

Comment: I think, we have no possibilities to do it, because exceptions should not have long and formatted description messages. Use another way to get additional information: logging, for example.

Comment: Just a note, instead of using `throw`, you should instead use `DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector().newUserError`. See user facing errors (https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/error-handling#user-facing-errors) or the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the exception text is not supported. If you need additional information about exceptional behavior, Александр Ермолин is correct in suggesting logging. See [Apps Script Logging](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/debug#apps_script_logging) for details on how to add logging to a connector.