# How to concat two fields with a new line in the middle in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

First, this is **not** the same as [How to make a new line in Google Data Studio in the exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915469/how-to-make-a-new-line-in-google-data-studio-in-the-exception) because that one is for writing a new connector and I am not trying to do that.

I want to concat two fields in a table column and put a new-line in the middle. Using `\n` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built calculated fields like this:

```
concat([Field1],"\n","\n",[Field2])
```

that result in this within a table:

> Field 1
>
> Field 2

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when using a custom data source concatenating the new line character would not work under any tests I performed (I used every text manipulation function they [have](https://support.google.com/datastudio/table/6379764?hl=en&ref_topic=7570421)). That approach, which matches Kellie's answer was:

```
concat(field1, '\n\n', field2)
```

This only works with google analytics data sources where there isn't a date range dimension (I didn't test gsheets/others) and you must have "wrap text" on the table body enabled. The work-around I found was to *NOT use data studio formatting in that you can put this in your data connector query/stored procedure. A PostgreSQL example:

```
select 
concat(field1, e'\n\n', field2) as newfield
from datatable;
```

Hopefully the datastudio team will fix this bug in the future (edit: the bug was with pivot tables, in that they do not recognize the new lines).